# Windows 10 App Installer Fails for Locally Hosted Package

Tags: uwp, appx

Trying to install a Windows 10 app package from a link resembling `ms-appinstaller:?source=http://localhost/myapp.appinstaller` hosted locally returns this error in the App Installer dialog:

> Error in parsing the app package.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 "Immersive" apps **cannot send requests to the local computer**. This includes the App Installer application.

After enabling an exemption to this security feature using Fiddler the link works fine.

You can also add an exemption at the command line with:

```
PS C:\> checknetisolation loopbackexempt -a -n="Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_1.0.32912.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe"
```

But it doesn't seem to take effect immediately, might have to reboot or something.